# Groovy to Biginteger

Tags: string, groovy, biginteger, base32

As the reverse of i.toString(32) is there a better (i.e. working) method to use instead of

```
i = Integer.parseInt(string, 32)
```

to create a BigInteger, as the string I want to pass is 11 'characters' long? (D4KJI9QLC3L) gives me

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "D4KJI9QLC3L"
Parameters:{val=14800099002200181, str=D4KJI9QLC3L}
```

If I add .toBigInteger() to the end it deos not seem to help at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new BigInteger(string, 32);
```